# How can i store the order

Tags: mysql

I have a questionnaire table and a question table.

I need to record the order of questions in my questionnaire, it may require another table.

Example:

A questionnaire may display question 42, then 56 then 14

Another questionnaire may record question 34, 67, 56, 27

The same questions used by multiple questionnaires.

**Questionnaire**:

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(255)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Question**:

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(255)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| question | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: How do you know which questions are in each questionnaire?  Where are you storing that?

Comment: I don't, the end user will pick which questions will be in a specific questionnaire. I just don't know how to store the order in a database.

Comment: One way is to have a `sortOrder` field in each row.  When you store the question IDs, set `sortOrder` to its position.

Comment: can you show me an example? I am unsure if you want the sortOrder in the question table or questionnaire table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create a third table to link the questions to the questionnaire.  Something like this:

**questionnaire_link**:

```
questionnaire_id    question_id    sortOrder
       1                42            1
       1                56            2
       1                14            3
       2                34            1
       2                67            2
       2                56            3
       2                27            4
```

(make sure to add indexes to this table)

Then you can make a query like this to get all the questions:

```
SELECT question.name FROM question
JOIN questionnaire_link ON question.id = questionnaire_link.question_id
WHERE questionnaire_link.questionnaire_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a M:M relationship table between Question and Questionnaire probably with the fk's for Question.id and Questionnaire.id and a column for the number question it was. That way you can find the questions per questionnaire id and sort by question number and join with the question table.

Comment: I don't understand how that would be able to record specific order to display the questions.

Comment: So your table would have `Questionnaire_id`, `Question_id`, and `QuestionNumber`. The order that the questions appeared in would be stored in the `QuestionNumber` column. When you `Select From Question_Questionnaire WHERE Questionnaire_id = 5;` to find the Question's that are in that specific Questionnaire. You can add a `JOIN ON Question_Questionnaire.Questionnaire_id = Question.id` and `SORT BY QuestionNumber ASC`. (There's probably an error in one of those queries, my SQL syntax is still meh)